# What do you call these leather straps with metallic ornament worn over a robe?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call these leather straps with metallic ornament worn over a robe? I am guessing this is something only Roman legionaire wore although I am not sure. Is there a word for it?

Comment: Have you found one on a picture of a Roman legionnaire? That is not a typical item of dress in the West. "open-work" strap leather vest. I doubt there is an actual term.

Comment: Nope, not really, but it looks like something from the Roman empire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No specific word in English.  There is a word in Latin "phalera" for the metal discs.  This word is borrowed into English (in the same way that "kimono" or "sari" are borrowed). Those who are not experts in Roman history won't know this word. The leather straps are just straps.  You might call the leather straps a "harness". and the phalaræ are medallions.

They would be worn over a legionnaire's armour during parades etc.

Comment: Yeah, so you could just say: phalera harness.